# ¿Porque ExecuteNonQuery() me da el siguiente error?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Buenas pondre mi codigo aqui y haber si alguien me puede decir que error tengo aqui porque no logro verlo

```
public List<EntidadProducto> listarProductosCD(SqlConnection conexion, int ID, String nombre, decimal precio)
    {
        List<EntidadProducto> listaProductos = new List<EntidadProducto>(); 
        CapaDProducto ocdProducto = new CapaDProducto();

        using (conexion)
        {
            String consultaSqlUpdate = "UPDATE PRODUCTS SET ProductName=@ProductName, UnitPrice=@UnitPrice WHERE=" + ID;
            SqlCommand comando = new SqlCommand(consultaSqlUpdate, conexion);
            comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductName", nombre);
            comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UnitPrice", precio);

            int filaAfectados = comando.ExecuteNonQuery();

            String consultaSql = "SELECT * FROM PRODUCTS";

            SqlCommand comando2 = new SqlCommand(consultaSql, conexion);

            SqlDataReader lectura = comando2.ExecuteReader();

            while (lectura.Read())
            {
                EntidadProducto oentProducto = new EntidadProducto();
                oentProducto.idProducto = lectura.GetInt32(lectura.GetOrdinal("ProductID"));
                oentProducto.Nombre = lectura.GetString(lectura.GetOrdinal("ProductName"));
                oentProducto.Precio = lectura.GetDecimal(lectura.GetOrdinal("UnitPrice"));
                listaProductos.Add(oentProducto);
            }

            lectura.Close();
        }

        return listaProductos;
    }
```

En la linea int filaAfetados me sale lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy almacenando el resultado en una variable entera porque me da error de sintaxis en el "="? Decir que soy nuevo en ASP.net a lo mejor hay algo anterior a el que estoy haciendo mal, ya que estoy ejecutando la consulta de acción y tampoco me modifica los datos, a lo mejor el la sentencia SQL hay algún error. Espero me puedan ayudar. Gracias.

Comment: Puedes indicarnos que valor obtienes en tu variable `consultaSqlUpdate` antes de realizar el `ExecuteNonQuery`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Buenas Ronald,

Tu error se debe a que tienes un error de sintaxis en la consulta SQL:

```
String consultaSqlUpdate = "UPDATE PRODUCTS SET ProductName=@ProductName, 
UnitPrice=@UnitPrice WHERE=" + ID;
```

Si te fijas, en el `WHERE` no le estas pasando que campo tiene que ser igual a `ID`, entonces te da error de sintaxis cerca del `'='` ya que no puede reconocer que campo debe comparar con `ID`:

Te debería quedar una cosa así:

```
String consultaSqlUpdate = "UPDATE PRODUCTS SET ProductName=@ProductName, 
UnitPrice=@UnitPrice WHERE ProductID=" + ID;
```

Answer (score 1):

En la variable String que tu defines la consulta de actualizacion se encuentra realizada de manera erronea

```
String consultaSqlUpdate = "UPDATE PRODUCTS SET ProductName=@ProductName, UnitPrice=@UnitPrice WHERE ProductID=" + ID;
```

Recuerda los fundamentos basicos para realizar un update en una consulta sql.

```
UPDATE table_name
SET column1 = value1, column2 = value2, ...
WHERE condition;
```

Answer (score 0):

Mi hermano ese valor es porque no lo estas definiendo si es procedimiento almacenado o query.
te falto este codigo:

```
comando.CommandType = CommandType.Text;


public List<EntidadProducto> listarProductosCD(SqlConnection conexion, int ID, String nombre, decimal precio)
    {
        List<EntidadProducto> listaProductos = new List<EntidadProducto>(); 
        CapaDProducto ocdProducto = new CapaDProducto();

        using (conexion)
        {
            String consultaSqlUpdate = "UPDATE PRODUCTS SET ProductName=@ProductName, UnitPrice=@UnitPrice WHERE=" + ID;
            SqlCommand comando = new SqlCommand(consultaSqlUpdate, conexion);
 comando.CommandType = CommandType.Text;            
comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductName", nombre);
            comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UnitPrice", precio);

            int filaAfectados = comando.ExecuteNonQuery();

            String consultaSql = "SELECT * FROM PRODUCTS";

            SqlCommand comando2 = new SqlCommand(consultaSql, conexion);

            SqlDataReader lectura = comando2.ExecuteReader();

            while (lectura.Read())
            {
                EntidadProducto oentProducto = new EntidadProducto();
                oentProducto.idProducto = lectura.GetInt32(lectura.GetOrdinal("ProductID"));
                oentProducto.Nombre = lectura.GetString(lectura.GetOrdinal("ProductName"));
                oentProducto.Precio = lectura.GetDecimal(lectura.GetOrdinal("UnitPrice"));
                listaProductos.Add(oentProducto);
            }

            lectura.Close();
        }

        return listaProductos;
    }
```

Te adjunto un ejemplo:

```
public void Usp_MostrarIncidentes(Int32 opt,String username,Int32 IdAtencionTarea)
        {
            SqlDataReader reader;

            SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(ObtenerCadenaConexion());
            cn.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Usp_MostrarIncidentes", cn);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@opt", SqlDbType.Int).Value = opt;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@username", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 250).Value = username;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@idatenciontarea", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 250).Value = IdAtencionTarea;

            var students = new List<ListaIncidencias>();
            reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                var student = new ListaIncidencias
                {
                    Minutos = Convert.ToInt32(reader[0].ToString()),
                    Id = Convert.ToInt32(reader[1].ToString()),
                    Fecha = Convert.ToString(reader[2].ToString()),
                    TipoIncidencia = reader[3].ToString(),
                    Sub_TipoIncidencia = reader[4].ToString(),
                    Estado = reader[5].ToString(),
                    Ver = reader[6].ToString()

                };
                students.Add(student);
            }
            var js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            Context.Response.Write(js.Serialize(students));

        }
```

Comment: Sólo se tiene que indicar el CommandType si es diferente a query SQL, como tu muestras en tu ejemplo, un Stored Procedure, pero si no lo indicas por defecto esta seleccionado que es una query